# What is a right way to map composite relationships in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I have a class called Topic, which may have prerequisites which are other Topics. What is the right way to map such a relationship. Should I do something like this ?

The Model you see below is a Play Framework Model class.

```
@Entity
public class Topic extends Model {
    @OneToMany
    public Set<Topic> prerequisites;
}
```

Or should I use another model class to manage the pre-requisite relationship ?

```
@Entity
public class TopicPrerequisites extends Model {
    @OneToOne
    public Topic theTopic;

    //or maybe this should be @ManyToMany ???
    @OneToMany
    public Set<Topic> prerequisites;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can a Topic be a pre-requisite for more than one Topic? If so, I would do the following:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Topic> prerequisites;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="prerequisites")
private List<Topic> topics;
```

An extra Entity for the relation would be unnecessary in my view.

Comment: That's very interesting. I did not realize I could have the same Entity as the owning and owned side. Thanks.